# Sails 1.0 Models without primary key

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I try to use new version 1.0 and refactoring my project. I have one problem and i don't now how i can solve her. Some tables on my BD don't have primary keys and when i migrate to sails 1.0, i have this error

> In model `friends`: The primary key is set to `id`, but no such
>   attribute was found on the model. You must define an `id` attribute in
>   `api/Friends.js` or in `config/models.js`. See
>   http://sailsjs.com/upgrading#?changes-to-model-configuration for
>   info

Can i use my model without primary keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have the same problem i used to change the primarykey this:
in file config/model.js

```
attributes: {
      id: { 
         type: 'number', 
         autoIncrement: true, 
      },
    }

    and in the model api/any_model.js i used:

    tableName : 'table',
    attributes: {
      id: { 
       type: 'number',  
       columnName : 'column_you_like_to_be_a_primaryKEY',
       required : true
      },
    }
```