# SailsJS: How to disable primary key attribute?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I keep getting this error.

```
The primary key is set to `id`, but no such attribute was found on the model.
```

My table in the database does not use any primary keys and there are no tutorials on how to disable the primary key attribute in sails.

Is there a way for me to query a model without specifying an id attribute or a primary key?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49736218/sails-1-0-models-without-primary-key

Comment: More info on [primary keys for Sails.JS](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-setting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have some kind of primary key in your model. The way the sails docs recommend to do that is to still use the 'id' attribute, but to give it a custom columnName. e.g. in the model:

```
id: {
    type: 'number',
    columnName: 'employeeID',
    required: true
{
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually had to do the id attribute but I was wondering if I have a transaction table that does not have any primary id at all.